# Filtrar dados de várias colunas sql

Tags: sql

estou precisando de ajuda com um banco de dados, seria fazer um distinct com varias colunas, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e a saída seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teria como fazer isso no sql server?

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct coluna
from
(
 select coluna1 coluna from tabela
 union
 select coluna2 from tabela
 union
 select coluna3 from tabela
 union
 select coluna4 from tabela
)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica... Consegui resolver aqui com ela.